# UIWebView title is not showing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using  following line of code for extracting title of a web page.

> NSString *title =  [webView
>   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];

This is working fine if i am doing the same on a separate project. But in my real project this code is not showing proper title as showing on a browser .(My app has so many webviews ans URL). Is this any kind of Cache problem? Please suggest an answer.

Comment: is it showing you previous title?

Comment: Yes. Previous title is showing.

Comment: Before loading next page or anything into WebView write this line `[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];` and after this line load your actual url. try this hope it will help you

Comment: @MohitPopat..If you have any answer.Please suggest me .

Comment: Shall I write the above in shouldStartLoadWithRequest method ???

Comment: write this before you are loading a new url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58868/discussion-between-jaya-and-mohit-popat).

Comment: @MohitPopat For what reason would you do that? It maybe an empty string but is still a pointless line and loading of the webview.

Comment: When creating your `NSURLRequest` you can add a cache policy (Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) Just add a cache policy of `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` so it doesn't load from the cache like it sounds like it's doing.